# Missing datepicker in Django 1.3 admin

Tags: django, django-admin, datepicker, django-1.3

Using Django 1.3, I am unable to see a datepicker for a Date or DateTime field in admin.

**Model**
    `Class xxxx:`
    `departure_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'Departure Date')`

**Admin**
    `from django.forms import ModelForm`
    `admin.site.register(models.Schedule)`

**settings.py**
    `MEDIA_ROOT = "/mnt/django/project_green/media/"`
    `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`
    `STATIC_ROOT = "/mnt/django/project_green/static/"`
    `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
    `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'`

**apache access.log**
Seeing this weird 404 error
    `"GET /mnt/django/project_green/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1159`

**source of admin page**
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css" />` 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/forms.css" />`
`<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->`

`<script type="text/javascript">window.__admin_media_prefix__ = "/static/admin/";</script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/mnt/django/project_green/admin/jsi18n/"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js">`        
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>` 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>`

Thanks
George

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem: not being able to see date picker in django admin.
The cause of the problem was a bug in **collectstatic** command: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15636

I ran **collectstatic** on Windows, and because of the bug, file `/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js` became lowercased: `datetimeshortcuts.js`
So when I deployed it on Linux to be served by Apache, link /`static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js` gave 404 error.
Solution is simple: either migrate to Django 1.4 or run **collectstatic** on Linux.